# Enable GPIO on ARM STM32G030K6

Tags: arm, embedded, stm32, gpio, bare-metal

I am trying to learn to program the STM32G030K6 by directly manipulating the registers (without relying on CubeMX). My program is intended to set pin PA5 to high.

```
// Target:  STM32G030K6T6
// Goal:    Set pin PA5 to high

#include "stm32g0xx.h"          // Device header

int main(void)
{
    RCC->IOPENR |= 1;           // Enable GPIOA Clock
    GPIOA->MODER |= 0x400;      // Set GPIOA MODE5 to a general purpose output
    GPIOA->ODR = 0x20;          // Set PA5 high

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

The program does not effect PA5 at all. 
I have successfully tested the setup with a CubeMX blink program to prove it is not a hardware issue.

[STM32G030K6: Data Sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g030k6.pdf)

[STM32G030K6: Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/fd/a3/20/58/ac/b0/48/23/DM00463896/files/DM00463896.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00463896.pdf)

Comment: from the ref manual MODER resets to mostly ones, by orring you end up with mostly ones which is analog mode, if you want to make it a general purpose output then and with ~(3<<(5<<1)) and then orr with 1<<(5<<1)

Comment: you can use BSRR to not mess with the other pins in that register (instead of odr).  BSRR = 1 << (5+0);   then try BSRR =  1<<(5+16);

Comment: and not all designs are such that a high level turns the led on, sometimes low is on, old days you could sink more than source, so old timers (and those they taught) might make it so low is on.

Comment: my guess is you are using gcc, but if using clang there is a bug related to using a while(1) loop that I cant remember them fixing, but at the same time have not checked on it in a while.  examine the disassembly to confirm it isnt returning, for some reason some sandbox environments undoes things when you return from main rather than go into a simple infinite loop.  so check the disassembly once MODER is confirmed if it doesnt work.

Comment: I'm clearly really out of my depth here.  I don't really understand all the "<<" things you wrote.  If it helps I was able to get this code to work using the STM32F446RE using the same code with one difference.  "RCC->IOPENR" was "RCC->AHB1ENR".  I changed it because the G0 MCU didn't route it's GPIO's through the AHB bus like the F446 did.  Otherwise everything seemed the same so I can't understand why it won't work on the G0 board.

Comment: because you have the pin set for analog mode not output mode.  do MODER &= 0xFFFFF7FF instead of orring with 0x400

Comment: better yet do both

Comment: if you want to work at this level it is wise that you learn masking and shifting.

Comment: I completely agree.  I changed MODER to "MODER &= 0xFFFFF7FF" as you said.  Unfortunately still doesn't work.

Comment: define work. did you also try to reset the pin instead of set the pin?  are you sure it is PA5?

Comment: what does the schematic show, how about this what board is this?

Comment: how do you know it is even saving/running your program?

Comment: there are other items that have to be right for this to work, are you sure the image is built right with the vector table up front?  is the vector table right?  is the stack pointer init value right?

Comment: By "work" I mean it still fails to set PA5 to high. Yes, using BSRR I tried setting and resetting. Neither set PA5 high. Yes I am 100% sure it is PA5.

Comment: There is no schematic. The setup is the mcu on a breakout board. With an led and resistor between PA5 and GND. It's worth mentioning again that this circuit does work when the code is generated using STM32 CubeMX which leads me to believe it is purely a software issue.

Comment: I know it is uploading because the console output from Keil uVision says something along the lines of "uploaded and verified" (I don't have the exact message at the moment but I'll get it if its relevant).

Comment: Regarding your last comment I'm honestly not sure what those things are. I am very new to this.

Comment: if it is a breakout board then there is no way for kiel to talk to it and program it so it is more than a breakout board.  even a breakout board has a schematic.  It is a software issue, but that does not automatically mean it is the lines of code you are looking at if you looked at the registers in the manual as I had you can see the errors in your original code, specifically moder.  But which rail does the led/resistor tie to on the other side. gpio - resistor/led - gnd or vcc?  so is high or low going to make the led work?

Comment: did you buy this board from somewhere?  if so where and/or what was the part number or a link

Comment: I can definitely help you through this, no problem whatsoever, but there are a number of factors.  The main() C code is on a small portion of the whole picture and you have to have all of it right for it to work. Having that C code correct doesnt mean it will work in any way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206176/discussion-between-m-p-and-old-timer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I have figured out from you so far is that you bought/acquired this part put it down on a breakout board.  Have applied power and ground, added an led and resistor, and have an stlink hooked up.  Can use CubeMX and make it work are using Kiel.

So I have made many a breakout board put the leds and such on the board because I got tired of wiring up items separately.   The parts I have used you needed to make sure VDD and VDDA were connected but yours it is the same pin, check.  VDD and VSS no doubt if you have it working.  NRST pulled up for good measure although I think not required as there is an internal pull up, but BOOT0 did need a pull down, but this is an STM32G and you have pointed out that SWCLK and BOOT0 share the same pin.  ST sadly is going away from the on chip bootloader or at least it is disabled by the factory

> ST production value: 0xDFFF E1AA

> Bit 24 nBOOT_SEL

> 0: BOOT0 signal is defined by BOOT0 pin value (legacy mode)

> 1: BOOT0 signal is defined by nBOOT0 option bit

So as shipped a new part BOOT0 is not something you can rely on to get into the bootloader and use a uart solution to download code into the flash, nor can you use it to get yourself unbricked while doing this level of work.

So the stlink is connected you said Kiel can talk to the part, so that is all in theory fine, not the problem.

I don't have Kiel off hand, but everyone can get a gnu cross compiler or build one from sources.

```
apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi  gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

The code below does not care about arm-non-eabi- vs arm-linux-gnueabi- variations on the cross compiler it is independent of those differences, it just needs the compiler assembler and linker.

Now this will probably again get into a personal opinion battle with certain other SO users.  Work through the noise.  I am specifically avoiding CMSIS, I have seen the implementation, and you should inspect it to, for now you don't want to add that risk to your code, remove it and add it later as desired.  This is my style it specifically controls the instruction used for access, everything about is based on a lot of experience even though you don't see that, designed for the reader to have a high chance of success.  Make it your own if/when you get this to work and/or the side comments which is my real goal may help you examine the binary you are building with your own tool to eliminate common traps.

It is not simply a case of getting the C code in main() right for bare-metal code to work you need the whole thing from reset on to be right.

Flash based version:

flash.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
stacktop: .word 0x20001000
.word reset
.word hang
.word hang

.thumb_func
reset:
    bl notmain
    b hang
.thumb_func
hang:   b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

notmain.c

```
void PUT32 ( unsigned int, unsigned int );
unsigned int GET32 ( unsigned int );
void dummy ( unsigned int );

#define RCC_BASE        0x40021000
#define RCC_IOPENR      (RCC_BASE+0x34)

#define GPIOA_BASE      0x50000000
#define GPIOA_MODER     (GPIOA_BASE+0x00)
#define GPIOA_OTYPER    (GPIOA_BASE+0x04)
#define GPIOA_BSRR      (GPIOA_BASE+0x18)

#define DCOUNT 2000000

int notmain ( void )
{
    unsigned int ra;
    unsigned int rx;

    ra=GET32(RCC_IOPENR);
    ra|=1<<0; //enable port a
    PUT32(RCC_IOPENR,ra);

    ra=GET32(GPIOA_MODER);
    ra&=~(3<<(5<<1)); //clear bits 10,11
    ra|= (1<<(5<<1)); //set bit 10
    PUT32(GPIOA_MODER,ra);

    ra=GET32(GPIOA_OTYPER);
    ra&=~(1<<5); //clear bit 5
    PUT32(GPIOA_OTYPER,ra);

    for(rx=0;;rx++)
    {
        PUT32(GPIOA_BSRR, (1<<(5+ 0)) );
        for(ra=0;ra<DCOUNT;ra++) dummy(ra);
        PUT32(GPIOA_BSRR, (1<<(5+16)) );
        for(ra=0;ra<DCOUNT;ra++) dummy(ra);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    rom : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > rom
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > rom
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

build

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 flash.s -o flash.o
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -ffreestanding  -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -c notmain.c -o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T flash.ld flash.o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

Again you can replace arm-none-eabi with arm-linux-gnueabi if that is what you have/found.  This code doesn't care about the differences.

The point here is for the processor to boot:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0
 8000004:   08000011    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r4}
 8000008:   08000017    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r4}
 800000c:   08000017    stmdaeq r0, {r0, r1, r2, r4}

08000010 <reset>:
 8000010:   f000 f808   bl  8000024 <notmain>
 8000014:   e7ff        b.n 8000016 <hang>

08000016 <hang>:
 8000016:   e7fe        b.n 8000016 <hang>
```

The application flash starts at 0x08000000 in the ARM memory space, called the Main Flash Memory in the reference manual.  Depending on the boot strap settings 0x08000000 will be mirrored at 0x00000000, as documented in the ARM manuals this is where the vector table lives.  The first word is a value loaded into the stack pointer on reset, the word at address 0x00000004 (which would be mirrored to 0x08000004) is the reset vector.

The above used the disassembler so it is trying to disassemble those values as instructions they are values/vectors ignore the disassembly for that table.

Assuming we can get the tools to put this binary in the flash at the desired location then

```
08000000 <_start>:
 8000000:   20001000    value loaded into sp on reset
 8000004:   08000011    reset vector
```

The reset vector is the address of the code to execute for that exception with the lsbit set to indicate thumb mode, the lsbit is stripped it does not go into the pc.  So the reset vector address here is 0x08000010 which is correct:

```
08000010 <reset>:
 8000010:   f000 f808   bl  8000024 <notmain>
 8000014:   e7ff        b.n 8000016 <hang>
```

And can follow this to notmain, name of the C entry point is not important, and some tools will add extra stuff it sees the label main(), have not seen one of those for years but continue to do this to also prove the point it doesn't matter.

So if this is put in the main flash at arm address 0x08000000 then this code will boot and run up to the C code.

Note sram starts at 0x20000000 and the RM shows this part has 32MBytes of sram so it has at least 0x1000 bytes to cover this project with plenty of extra room.

```
 8000026:   481b        ldr r0, [pc, #108]  ; (8000094 <notmain+0x70>)
 8000028:   f7ff fff8   bl  800001c <GET32>
 800002c:   2101        movs    r1, #1
 800002e:   4301        orrs    r1, r0
 8000030:   4818        ldr r0, [pc, #96]   ; (8000094 <notmain+0x70>)
 8000032:   f7ff fff1   bl  8000018 <PUT32>
...
 8000094:   40021034    andmi   r1, r2, r4, lsr r0
```

Be it as I have programmed or through your program and CMSIS or HAL headers, you should see 0x40021034 being used in some form.  Note this part of yours is a cortex-m0+ so it only has a limited number of thumb2 extensions note that bl is two separate 16 instructions that can be spaced apart, but are pretty much always found as a pair, they are two instructions, the rest of the instructions need to be 16 bit, if you see something.w in the disassembly or instructions other than bl being 32 or 16*2 bits then that may be a thumb2 instruction and that won't run on this processor and may be some setting you have used when building this code, you can see with this toolchain I have specifically called out an m0 which is effectively the same as m0+ from an instruction set perspective (architecture armv6-m).  You do not want armv7-m for this chip it won't work, there are about a 100 or so instructions in armv7-m that won't work on armv6-m based chips.

The orring of the bit in the io enable register should resemble a read (ldr) from 0x40021034 a modification of the value read and a write (str) to that same address.

Your code as posted would have worked on other STM32 parts as many of them initialize the MODER register (if that part uses that flavor of GPIO peripheral) to zeros for most of the pins which is input.  This part documents that most of the pins reset to 0b11 which is analog mode, curious why but whatever.

> Reset value:

> 0xEBFF FFFF for port A

> 0xFFFF FFFF for other ports

So you can't simply set one of the two bits to change the mode if the bits started off as 0b00 then setting one can turn it into 0b01, but for this part you can either just clear bit 11 or better control both bits and not rely on the reset state, so clear the two bits and set one of them or clear one and set the other

5<<1 means 5 shifted left one  0b101 shift a zero in from the right gives 0b1010 which is a 0xA which is 10 this is a visual way to see that I am messing with PA5 and the number 5 is there, but for this register pin 5 mode settings are bits 10 and 11.   3 << (5<<1) means 3<<10 which is bits 10 and 11.  the tilde means invert the whole thing so 00000C00 is the 3<<10 invert that you get FFFFF3FF which anded with the moder value will zero bits 10 and 11.  now orr with 00000400 1<<10 to set bit 10.

We want the output at least for now to be a push-pull not open drain so even though the reset value is already push-pull, I clear it for good measure.  Now I normally don't bother with the pull up or other gpio setup register, I mess with these two MODER and OTYPER for the STM32 parts that use this GPIO peripheral (you will see that not all STM32 parts use the same IP, the STM32F103 uses a different one for example, check it out.

So in some way confirm that CMSIS or not that the code produced is messing with these registers.  From the documentation GPIOA starts at 0x50000000.  so 0x50000000 and 0x50000004 registers.

Because this part has a GPIO BSRR register its a nice feature just use it for now so that you don't accidentally mess with other pins.

The dummy loop burns time so that in this case the led blinks on and off, you have to tune the DCOUNT based on the clock used for the processor when you get this running not too fast not too slow, just right.  Doing it this way with an external function it is no longer dead code ( for(ra=0;ra<DCOUNT;ra++) continue; ) the compiler is forced to build it without using a volatile request.

No the code doesn't actually hit return(0);  some compilers are not that smart and complain. (some are that smart and complain that you can't get there, YMMV)

All of these pieces need to be in place to have a half a chance of this working. Its not just about a few lines of C code.

With an stlink the kiel tools are fine and I would hope there is a way to examine memory space, you will want to examine 0x08000000 and compare that to the binary generated by the tool, and hopefully there is a way to examine the output of the tool as well to see what it built, easy to do with gnu.

You can use openocd instead of kiel to load and examine things from a command line it would be something in the form

```
openocd -f stlink.cfg -f target.cfg
```

and then in another window

```
telnet localhost 4444
```

gdb adds a whole lot more unknowns...

then you can use

```
mdw 0x08000000 40
```

In the telnet window to see what is in that main flash and then compare it to the loadable portion of the binary to see if your program is really there, if your program is not actually there then no matter what you do to the C code it wont make it blink.

There are ways to use openocd to flash parts, but it is very vendor/part specific as they have to add that capability to openocd and you have to have the right version, from memory it is something along the lines of

```
flash write_image erase notmain.elf
```

if using a "binary" with address information in it, if you are using a memory image then you need to put the address on that command line 0x08000000

Some st parts come locked or let's say boards like some blue pills where this doesn't work, virgin parts I don't know that I have seen locked, you bought loose parts it appears so they should not be locked.

If you get openocd working and gnu then you could also try using sram without having to have flash support initially.

sram.s

```
.cpu cortex-m0
.thumb

.thumb_func
.global _start
_start:
    ldr r0,=0x20001000
    mov sp,r0
    bl notmain
    b .

.thumb_func
.globl PUT32
PUT32:
    str r1,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl GET32
GET32:
    ldr r0,[r0]
    bx lr

.thumb_func
.globl dummy
dummy:
    bx lr
```

sram.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x1000
}
SECTIONS
{
    .text : { *(.text*) } > ram
    .rodata : { *(.rodata*) } > ram
    .bss : { *(.bss*) } > ram
}
```

Since this part uses a vector table and what is about to be described is using the debugger to place and run a program in sram, volatile so when you reset/reboot it is lost, but it provides a way to experiment without having to get flash writing working.

We will tell the debugger to start execution at 0x20000000 so we want there to be an instruction there not a vector table.

```
arm-none-eabi-as --warn --fatal-warnings -mcpu=cortex-m0 sram.s -o sram.o
arm-none-eabi-ld -o notmain.elf -T sram.ld sram.o notmain.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D notmain.elf > notmain.list
arm-none-eabi-objcopy notmain.elf notmain.bin -O binary
```

always inspect your binary on a new project before running

```
Disassembly of section .text:

20000000 <_start>:
20000000:   4804        ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; (20000014 <dummy+0x2>)
20000002:   4685        mov sp, r0
20000004:   f000 f808   bl  20000018 <notmain>
20000008:   e7fe        b.n 20000008 <_start+0x8>

2000000a <PUT32>:
2000000a:   6001        str r1, [r0, #0]
2000000c:   4770        bx  lr

2000000e <GET32>:
2000000e:   6800        ldr r0, [r0, #0]
20000010:   4770        bx  lr

20000012 <dummy>:
20000012:   4770        bx  lr
20000014:   20001000    andcs   r1, r0, r0

20000018 <notmain>:
20000018:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
```

and that looks good.

with openocd you can now

reset halt
load_image notmain.elf
resume 0x20000000

To run the program (might need a path, if you run openocd in the directory where the elf file is and/or you copy the elf file to the directory where you launched openocd (not telnet, openocd) then you usually don't need to put a path.

This is in sram not flash so may run faster and may want a larger value in the delay loop.

If you simply want to make the output high or low then just use the desired bsrr line and get rid of the loops, this code as written puts you in a safe infinite loop when you return from notmain, one that will not interfere with the gpio port, as part of your investigation of the binary you are building with your tool you need to confirm that the while loop you have placed is actually not dead code and was implemented (clang has been known to dead code this so others might as well) and some sandboxes undo stuff when you return from main so it could be that your code is now fine, but exits from main and the bootstrap undoes what you did to PA5 faster than you can see it.

That's all I can do so far, I have an stm32 cortex-m0+ part with a working openocd config if that helps, this is a different part but the core is the same if there isn't another tap then it should just work but you never know.

Short answer, your moder code wouldn't have worked, otherwise it looked good, but the C code is only part of the story required for success.  This long answer highlights the main points that have to be there for success in booting and setting up the led.  It is possible that both of us missed an additional enable, I don't have this part specifically so I cannot actually pull one out and run this code on it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I learned a ton from reading all of that. 
I found my original problem was my handling of the MODER register as you pointed out. For some reason after correcting this, the program would still not work at first. I then used the STM32Programmer tool to do a full chip erase. From there my original code with your MODER register correction loaded and worked correctly. I don't really understand how I bricked it before but it works perfectly now. Thank you for all of your help!